# Using a PCIe 6/8-pin connector on a modular PSU to power on a car head unit temporarily

Tags: power-supply, automotive, atx

I would like to temporarily wire up a standard 650W ATX to power on a car head unit to check if it is working for about 30 mins. Based the pinout below, do I hook up pins 1 and 4 (or 1 and 5) only?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From those connectors, yes. One 12V wire and one GND wire should power the device.

The larger problems are that you need to be able to turn the ATX supply on, and as it is not a general purpose power supply, it may not be able to power any arbitrary 12V loads. If the device is the only load, you may need to use tricks so the supply can power it, but the tricks your supply needs are specific to your supply.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's within the average capacity of your psu then yes that can work.